# Is Bluemix sign up page working?

Tags: ibm-cloud

Can't sign up for Bluemix.

After hitting submit, the [sign up page](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/registration/?Target=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole.ng.bluemix.net%2Flogin%3Fstate%3D%2Fhome%2Fonboard) suggests to check my email. I did and then my spam but nothing has arrived.

I had to submit a ticket with support. Their response was a suggestion to clear my  browser's cache. It wasn't that effective.

Any hypothesis?

Comment: this does not sound like a programming question!

Comment: Why does it has to be a programming question to be a valid question? This is a question related to ibm-bluemix after all.

Comment: Stackoveflow site is for asking specific programming questions. I flagged this Question as non-programming and if other members of the stackoverflow community thinks likewise,this post will be closed as off-topic else if others believe it as valid post, it will stay! That is how SO Community works :)

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that on the question rules section.

Answer (score 0):

The email Bluemix sent might be blocked by your or your company's mail server, you can raise a ticket asking Bluemix Support to send you confirmation email again. If it is still not working, you may need to check your mail server administrator if it is blocked. And you can double check your sign up information to make the email address is correct.

Comment: I used my correct gmail address. Anyway, I just found the proper forum to submit non-technical Bluemix questions. Thanks for the response.